# Simplify selector for multiple child elements of the same parent in .on()-method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I use this code to keep track whether there are any changes on a form:

```
$(document).on('input', '.track', function() {
    var form = $(this);
});
```

As this won't fire on *checkboxes*, *radio buttons* and *file input* I also use this snippet to handle those elements in a tracked form:

```
$(document).on('change', '.track [type="checkbox"], .track [type="radio"], .track [type="file"]', function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
});
```

My question is now: How can I simplify this selector?

```
.track [type="checkbox"], .track [type="radio"], .track [type="file"]
```

The forms come and go dynamically so I have to use the `.on()`-method and can't preselect all necessary elements, like `$('.track').find('[type="checkbox"], …');`

Comment: your selector `.track` should work. because the bigger selector says: gimme all elements with css class track and type checkbox and all elements with css class track and type radio... and so on. change "input" in your first code block to "change" and it will work

Comment: @JoshuaK Yes, it works indeed. I actually want to get rid of the `.track`-prefix (parent-selector) on every possible child element that I have to handle separately.

Comment: ok. but why not using `:checkbox`, `:file` and so on? but why do want to do that? `.track *` selects all elements inside the .track. and the change event is only fired by form elements... so you don't have to select them by yourself. you know what I mean?

Comment: please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48Lg7Lga/ and tell me what point of this solution you dn't like :)

Comment: @JoshuaK You're right. Argh - I thought I've tested it and it wasn't working. Seems I must have had a mistake somewhere else, but this is totally enough: `$(document).on('input change', '[data-form-track]', function() {});` Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: you are welcome :) have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Change your approach to not depend on the selector and handle within the callback itself using `event.target`

```
$(document).on('change', '.track', function(event) {
    if(['file', 'checkbox', 'radio'].indexOf($(event.target).attr('type')) > -1){
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One simplification is to use [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/), [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/), and [`:file`](http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/):

```
'.track :checkbox, .track :radio, .track :file'
```

And if you don't want to repeat yourself, you could do a little trick using [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
'.track :not(:not(:checkbox, :radio, :file))'
```

But then you start getting into "ugly" territory.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var typeArray = ['file', 'checkbox', 'radio'];
$(document).on('change', '.track', function(e) {
    if($.inArray(this.type, typeArray) === -1) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
    }
});
```